# Is it possible to save a temporary image or pdf of webpage using php in WordPress?

Tags: php

I want to save a temporary image or pdf of the current web page using php code in WordPress. I would ideally not want to use additional plug-ins but would be fine with it if that's the only way to do it.

I want it all to be in the background and to send it using php mail. I have the mail section figured out, I'm just stuck on saving the page as an image or pdf.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a `hacky answer`, but it's *kind* of possible. If you set up Codeception acceptance tests, using a headless browser such as Selenium or phantomjs, write a failing acceptance test, and it will put a screenshot in the log!

Acceptance tests are real easy:

```
 $I->amOnPage('/my-url/to/screenshot');
 $I->see('Something that clearly isnt on the page');
```

That will fail, and it will put a PNG screenshot in the log directory!

Like I say, very much a HACK, but it would work! 
http://codeception.com/quickstart

Comment: Just confirming. It's a screenshot and will record what's on the screen. If there is content of the screen, it will not record it. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your PHP/Wordpress server has no idea of what "the current webpage" looks like since it cannot render HTML (that's your browser's job).

However there are some PHP libraries such as [HTML2PDF](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) that could help you achieve this:

```
$content = '<Your string containing some HTML content>';
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
$html2pdf->output('myfile.pdf');
```

Keep in mind that you'll get a very basic rendering, without any dynamic content.